# Matlab can't create my ros action client：Failed to create a simple action client

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use this command to create a ros action client in matlab:

```
[actClient,goalMsg] = rosactionclient('/do_dishes');
```

However, an error occured:

```
Failed to create a simple action client with name /do_dishes and type action_tutorials/DoDishes. Verify that the action type is valid.
```

I do not know if I need to define the action message type in matlab.

DoDishes_client and DoDishes_server nodes worked well in ROS.

So who can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280439/matlab-can%27t-create-my-ros-action-client%EF%BC%9Afailed-to-create-a-simple-action-client/) by [ZouQiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/23923/zouqiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this proble.
We should "[Create Custom Messages from ROS Package](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/create-custom-messages-from-ros-package.html)" by ourselfs.

Firstly, install "[Robotics System Toolbox Interface for ROS Custom Messages](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49810-robotics-system-toolbox-interface-for-ros-custom-messages?s_tid=srchtitle)"

Secondly, because my packages and matlab are both in ubuntu system, so I just enter follow codes in matlab command window.

```
userfolder = '/home/robot/msg_gen';
rosgenmsg(userfolder);
```

and I had put my packages "action_tutorials" into msg_gen. Then message file will be generated in /msg_gen/matlab_gen  . You can watch https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/create-custom-messages-from-ros-package.html for more details.

---

Originally posted by [ZouQiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/23923/zouqiang/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SkullKrushur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39862/skullkrushur/) on 2019-02-05**:
I have done that but I couldn't use that custom message in Simulink. I can't even open it using " rosmsg('show','xxxxxx')" or " YYYY= rosmessage('XXXX')". My message is there in rosmsg list (Matlab) but i cant access it in matlab.